# Select from table with grouping by field and selecting max datetime with Django ORM

Tags: mysql, sql, django

I have a log of some events, where I store data about user views some advertising companies. 
I need to get a list of advertisements that viewed user and date of last view every advertisement in this list.
In other words, if I have three rows:

```
id | advertisement_id | user_id | datetime   | 
1  |       1          |     1   | 03.06.2014 |
2  |       1          |     1   | 04.06.2014 |
3  |       2          |     1   | 05.06.2014 |
```

I need to select second and third row.
I guess it schould be something like this:

```
user_campaigns = AdvertShowEvent.objects.filter(user=user).values_list('id', flat=True).distinct().latest('datetime')
```

But it does not work.
How can I dow this with Django ORM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be like this

```
AdvertShowEvent.objects.filter(user=user).values('advertisement').annotate(Max(‌​'datetime'), id=MAX('id')).values_list('id', flat=True)
```

Comment: It gives me all advertisement views (with repetition adwertisements), but I need only unique ads.

Comment: ah, sorry. then you have to use .values('advertisement_id'). Though you want to get latest for user. Sorry.

Comment: assuming your field is foreign key named `advertisement` it might be `.values('advertisement')` instead

Comment: well, I just realized you probably want to know ids of the rows. the only workaround I found is to make  `AdvertShowEvent.objects.filter(user=user).values('advertisement').annotate(Max('datetime'), id=MAX('id')).values_list('id', flat=True)`

Comment: Looks like something wrong with .annotate(Max(‌​'datetime'), id=MAX('id'))` statement.

Comment: well, this is probably the only way to pass `id`. I just tried and it worked for me. let me know if you have an issue still.